# Multi-categorical variable in linear regression

Tags: regression

I am trying to explain the variance in "wages" across different groups of the population. In my model, "wages" is a dependent variable. The key independent var is "groups" (Non-immigrant is the reference group). Then I add several controls such as age, education, occupation, etc. However, I have an issue with the occupation variable. In my dataset, **there are several occupation variables** that I can use:

(1) 10 categories of occupation: Management, Sales, Business, Health, ...

(2) Skill levels of occupation (5 categories): Management, Professional, Technical, Intermediate, Labor

(3) 40 categories of occupation (which is kind of a combination of (1) and (2)): Senior manager, middle manager, ...

**My questions:**

1/ I want to include both (1) and (2) in my model because both of them (occupation groups and skill levels have a strong impact on the variance of wages. However, there is one overlapping category (Management). How can I include both of them into the model without any issue?

2/ In case I can't include (1) and (2) in the same model, is it okay if I include all 40categories (actually 39 because 1 is committed as a reference group) into the model? I use the Census 2016 so the sample size is quite large. But I am still worried that too many categories may constrain my model because in addition to occupation, I also have levels of education, age categories and some other categorical variables as well.

Thank you very much for your answers in advance! Your help is much appreciated!

Rose

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You say there is overlap between Occupation and Skill because of the Management category. However, I'm wondering if "Management" might actually mean different things in terms of occupation and skill. Have you checked that the two indicator variables I{Occupation = "Management"} and I{Skill = "Management"} are the same?